# How to send post value to two separate functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I have a form and a submit action routed to `BaseController/FirstFunction`, but i need to POST some of the sent values to the `SecondFunction`. So how can i send a POST value to other functions.

Like this example: `FirstFunction` has a input value with the name "$value". I want the `SecondFunction` to use this "$value".

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class BaseController extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

    public function FirstFunction()
    {
      $value = "Test Value";
      /*Insert etc.*/
    }


    public function SecondFunction()
    {
      $insertData = [
        'product_id' => $value,
      ];
      /*Insert etc.*/
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a controller that decides which function to send the post request to?

Comment: Also, there is no reason you can't call one controller from another. For example, in FirstFunction() you can call SecondFunction()

Comment: For example, how can I send only one value between the functions ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You have a function and you want to send what over to what function? Let's say you have a request that calls the first function. What do you need to do that's in the second function? It sounds to me like you need a third function that both the first and second function can call that does some work

Comment: I just want to send a value from one function to another. For example, if I have a value in the first function $value = "Test Value", I want to use this value in the second function.

Comment: Make $value a parameter of the function. Then you call the function like SecondFunction($value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you form action to controller/common function and you will get form data in both function  FirstFunction() and  SecondFunction() .

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class BaseController extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

public function common(){
    $this->FirstFunction();
    $this->SecondFunction();

}

    public function FirstFunction()
    {
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);
    }


    public function SecondFunction()
    {
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not send post values to multiple functions. Instead you can do something like this:

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class BaseController extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
     parent::__construct();
    }

public function FirstFunction()
{
  $value = "Test Value";

  $this->SecondFunction($value);
  /*Insert etc.*/
}


public function SecondFunction($value)
{
  $insertData = [
    'product_id' => $value,
  ];
  /*Insert etc.*/
}

}
```

You can refer [this blog](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pass-data-between-functions-in-codeigniter/) and [this](https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/58454/passing-data-between-two-functions-in-my-controller-class).

I hope this will help you.